# Errors in linking during build with Core Plot

Tags: cocoa, xcode, linker, core-plot

I have just added a Core Plot view to my application based on a tutorial (http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application). I have put the Core Plot drawing code in the windowDidLoad method of the window controller for the window where I have included the CPLayerHostingView. The code for the plot is:

```
CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-6) 
                                               length:CPDecimalFromFloat(12)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-5) 
                                               length:CPDecimalFromFloat(30)];

CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5"] decimalValue];  
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLabelOffset = 3.0f;

axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5"] decimalValue];  
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLabelOffset = 3.0f;

CPScatterPlot *xSquaredPlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] 
                                initWithFrame:graph.defaultPlotSpace.bounds] autorelease];
xSquaredPlot.identifier = @"X Squared Plot";
xSquaredPlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
xSquaredPlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor redColor];
xSquaredPlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:xSquaredPlot];
```

When I build I get the following errors:

".objc_class_name_CPPlotRange", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CPPlotRange in HistogramWindowController.o

"_CPDecimalFromFloat", referenced from:
      -[HistogramWindowController windowDidLoad] in HistogramWindowController.o
      -[HistogramWindowController windowDidLoad] in HistogramWindowController.o
      -[HistogramWindowController windowDidLoad] in HistogramWindowController.o
      -[HistogramWindowController windowDidLoad] in HistogramWindowController.o

".objc_class_name_CPLineStyle", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CPLineStyle in HistogramWindowController.o

".objc_class_name_CPXYGraph", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CPXYGraph in HistogramWindowController.o

".objc_class_name_CPScatterPlot", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CPScatterPlot in HistogramWindowController.o

".objc_class_name_CPPlotSymbol", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CPPlotSymbol in HistogramWindowController.o

".objc_class_name_CPColor", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CPColor in HistogramWindowController.o

".objc_class_name_CPFill", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CPFill in HistogramWindowController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I've never encountered an error like this. Can anyone shed any light on what the problem might be?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you haven't linked in the framework correctly.  You've probably just added the framework to your project, `#import`ed the header, but forgot to make sure that the framework is actually getting linked into your target.

Comment: A very similar thing happened to me after checking out my project from SVN to recover and it was apparently missing a couple of my classes. Adding them back in resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are some instructions on [this wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) for incorporating the framework into Mac projects.  If you follow those, you should be able to avoid any problems with linking in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact same link errors. For me, the problem was I was trying to run my application in the simulator. I don't know if I missed something somewhere, but I could only run on a device. Once I started to do that, no link errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check whether your application target is set to include 64-bit support and whether the framework has such support (use the [file(1)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) command for the latter part). If you're building your app with 64-bit support, but try to link against a framework that doesn't have 64-bit support, the linker will throw errors like that when it tries to link the 64-bit portion of your app, while the 32-bit portions will succeed.

Comment: By default, the framework should be compiling a 32/64-bit Universal target, but you're right that this is something to watch for.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the QuarzCore framework as well. This fixed my linking errors.